# How to convert phenylacetic acid to 3-phenylpropionitrile?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I understand that phenylacetic acid reacts with $\ce{KSCN}$ can form phenylacetonitrile plus the side product ($\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{KSH}$). This is Letts nitrile synthesis

However, the problem is to convert phenylacetic acid to 3-phenylpropionitrile.
Is that possible? What reagents do we need?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add one carbon, the easiest source of this is as CN-.

Three steps.

1. Reduce phenylacetic acid to 2-phenylethanol (borane.THF is a good way)
2. Form the tosylate of the alcohol (TsCl, pyridine)
3. Treat the tosylate with NaCN in DMSO [reference here](https://www.gaylordchemical.com/synthesis-corner/cyanation/).